# How to add a new schema in a Visual Studio 2013 Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project, sql-server-2014

I need to create an additional schema with some database objects in it within a Visual Studio 2013 Database Project. How can I do this?

Comment: I clicked "Add New Item" and didn't find it in the list...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a new item to your project of **type Schema** (listed under SQL Server > Security).

For the objects that belong to this schema, add them as you normally would to your project. However they will default to the dbo schema so you will have to change that in each object's script (for example, `CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1` becomes `CREATE TABLE Schema1.Table1`)

Comment: Thanks! That's where it was hiding!

Answer (score 6):

To add a new Schema into a database project in Visual Studio, you need to follow below steps.

### Create a schema

- Right-click the database project in Solution Explorer
- Select **Add** `-->` **New Item**
- In the next window, select **Security** on the left-hand side (**Installed** `-->` **SQL Server** `-->` **Security**)
- In the list of file types, select **Schema**
- Give the schema a name, then click <kbd>Add</kbd>.

This will now create a new file with a `CREATE SCHEMA` T-SQL statement in it.

### Create table in a non-default schema

If you want to create a table belonging to this new schema, and follow the recommended folder structure, do the following:

- Create a folder `myschema` (where 'myschema' is whatever you called your schema)
- Create a folder `Tables` (and/or `Views`, `Stored Procedures` etc) under that folder
- Right-click that last folder, select **Add** `-->` **Table**
- As the name of the table, use the schema as a prefix: `myschema.MyNewTable.sql`.

This will create a file in the proper folder structure and in the proper schema. If the schema is misspelled or non-existing, you'll get an error telling you so.

### Move existing tables to a different schema

This approach works in newer versions of Visual Studio:

- Open the `*.sql` file containing a table definition
- Right-click the name of the table
- Select **Refactor** `-->` **Move to schema**
- Select the new schema in the dropdown box
- Check the global refactoring and accept the changes
- Fix by hand any code, like sql-as-string or dynamic sql that references the moved table.